# Embedded bookmark in J2ME app

Tags: java-me

Does anyone know if this is possible in J2ME;

I want to have an app that simply launches a browser when opened and directs the browser to a specific web page.

If so, is it widely supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet.platformRequest()` to launch the browser on almost all phones that support JavaME. This [article](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/platformRequest/) tells more about invoking platform services such as browser.

Comment: Gorkem, do you do any freelance work? if so, how I can contact you?